# Picking dates from a calendar with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to select two dates (date_from and date_to) in a pop-up window. The only way doing step-by-step with the mouse is by clicking in each calendar icon (see image) and picking the date from there. I'd like to set those values in the site with already selected dates.

[image]

Here is the HTML code (date_from):

```
<div class="field">
<i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar" ng-click="ParameterExportModal.openCalendar($event, 'from')"></i>
<input type="text" class="field" value="-" readonly="readonly">
<input id="from" type="text" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-dirty ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" style="display: none;" datepicker-popup="" is-open="ParameterExportModal.datepickers.from" ng-model="ParameterExportModal.form.start" close-text="Close" ng-required="true" required="required">
<!-- ngIf: isOpen -->
<span class="msg ng-scope" translate="invalid.field">Please enter a valid value</span>
</div>
```

I tried changing as I did previously to log in the site:

```
date_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='from']")
date_from.send_keys("01/01/2019")
```

But then I received this error message: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

And just something that I noticed, the line that contains the `id` field of the HTML code of both `input`'s is gray. I don't know if this impacts on something. Here it is how it looks like:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to share the URL? Generally I would click on the inputbox (from/to) then select the date directly in the calendar.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not... I thought about doing this but depending on the date the user wants, it'll be a lot more of clicks just to get to the date. That's why I want to "ask" the user first and just put the value there, but dont't know if it's possible

Comment: Can you check the events associated with the input, so that you can send the date and then trigger corresponding event. Eg: if the input is associated with `onchange` event then you have to click on the input, send the date and then trigger `onchange` event using javascript.

Comment: There are some date pickers where each date have it's own value `mm\dd\yyyy`, if that's the case with your date picker then you can directly click on the date element by using `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[date picker xpath goes here]//*[.='mm/dd/yyyy']").click()`

Comment: Tried that but it keeps bringing "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"... about the events, there are a lot of events related to the `input` line, including `change` and `input`, I think I need to trigger one of these

Comment: Have you tried to set the value using xpath `//i[contains(@ng-click,'from')]/input[@class='field']`?

Comment: Yes, just did it. Tried to directly set the value and, also, by the way you suggested and did not work... same error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. Even if I don't use the .click() property and just assigned it to a variable and print it, I receive this error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192484/discussion-between-supputuri-and-pedro-de-sa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" error nothing to do with the calendar. make sure you call the method correctly.

For example if you try to call `time(2)` that will cause this kind of error, you have to call `time.sleep(2)`.